# Using document.currentScript to append data to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append data into divs by passing their `id` as attributes in a `script` tag. In this example the `first-div` should get get 'test1' appended to it, and the `second-div` should get the 'test2' appended to it.

However, the result it that both 'test1' and 'test2' are appended to `second-div`. `first-div` is empty. I'm guessing it has to do with how `document.currentScript` is functioning. Is there any way to get the result I am looking for?

```
<div id="first-div"></div>
<div id="second-div"></div>

<script attr1="name1" attr2="name2" to-div="first-div" type="text/javascript">
  var this_script = document.currentScript;
  var attr1 = this_script.getAttribute('attr1');
  var attr2 = this_script.getAttribute('attr2');
  var append_div = this_script.getAttribute('to-div');

  $.ajax({
    url: "/dir?attr1=" + attr1,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#' + append_div).append("test1");
  });
</script>

<script attr1="name3" attr2="name4" to-div="second-div" type="text/javascript">
  var this_script = document.currentScript;
  var attr1 = this_script.getAttribute('attr1');
  var attr2 = this_script.getAttribute('attr2');
  var append_div = this_script.getAttribute('to-div');

  $.ajax({
    url: "/dir?attr1=" + attr1,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#' + append_div).append("test2");
  });
</script>
```

Also, in the solution, the scripts cannot have `id` attributes, which is why I am trying to use `document.currentScript`.

The reason for this is that the code will be hosted on my servers. The code will append information into the divs the user wants, given parameters passed through attributes on the script tag. In the end the user should be able to use:

```
<script attr1="var1" attr2="var2" to-div="custom-div" src="http://www.myurl.com/assets/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To insert data into their `custom-div` based on code I run on my servers dependend on the parameters `attr1` and `attr2` they provide.

Comment: Probably best if you just stop with this eerie approach and tell us what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: just a question of curiosity: why is it required that you have attributes on your script tag?

Comment: @Jonathan I provided more details on why I am trying to do this. Please, let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: @indubitablee edited the original post with more info

Comment: your code works fine [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OcgjGeizysJsqGAbl0Gz?p=preview)

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, for testing the code. You're right, it does work in that instance. I think where it goes wrong is handling ajax within the script. I'll update the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `var append_div` is a global variable and each time a new script tag is encountered it gets overwritten with the new value.

Since ajax is asynchronous , by the time the responses return the other script tags will have been evaluated so `append_div` will have the value of the last script tag.

You could fix this by creating a function that wraps the ajax

```
function doAjax(elementId, attr1) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/dir?attr1=" + attr1,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#' + elementId).append("test2");
        }
    });
}

doAjax(append_div, attr1);
```

An even better solution as pointed out by @Rhumborl is to use an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

```
(function( elementId, attr1){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/dir?attr1=" + attr1,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#' + elementId).append("test2");
        }
    });
}(elementId, attr1);
```

Or wrap all of your code in an IIFE and no arguments would need to be passed in.

```
(function(){
      var this_script = document.currentScript;
      var attr1 = this_script.getAttribute('attr1');
      var attr2 = this_script.getAttribute('attr2');
      var append_div = this_script.getAttribute('to-div');

      $.ajax({
        url: "/dir?attr1=" + attr1,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
          $('#' + append_div).append("test2");
        }
      });
}();
```

Comment: or an IIFE in each script to isolate the variables was gonna be my suggestion

Comment: @Rhumborl yes, that makes even more sense as the function won't get redeclared numerous times

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I'll test it as soon as I get back to my computer. Thanks.

Comment: The IIFE is actually the best choice IMO, avoids re-declaring the same function numerous times